# Rasterio set a unique name for each band

Tags: python, rasterio

I have an array of shape `(b, N, M)` which has `b` bands or images of size `N x M`. I am able to write them into a multiband `.tiff` file using:

```py
        band_nums = range(1, b + 1)
        with rasterio.open(file_path, 'w', **meta_data) as dst:
            dst.write(arrays, indexes=band_nums)
```

What I need to do, is to set a name for each band. Currently, it set default names of `Band_0, Band_1, ..., Band_b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `set_description` method :

```
 with rasterio.open(
    '.your_file.tif',
    'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    height=height,
    width=width,
    count=2,
    dtype=dtype,
    crs=crs,
    transform=transform,
 ) as dst:
    dst.write(band_1, 1)
    dst.set_band_description(1, 'Band 1 Name')
    dst.write(band_2, 2)
    dst.set_band_description(2, 'Band 2 Name')
```

Otherwise, as you suggested, this solution works as well :

```
dst.descriptions = tuple(['Band 1 name', 'Band 2 name', 'Band 3 name'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `set_band_description` wasn't exist in my case. Inspired by your answer, I fixed it like `dst.descriptions = tuple(['Band 1 name', 'Band 2 name', 'Band 3 name'])`. If you fix your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Done ! Nice way of doing it as well

Comment: It appears dst.set_band_description is deprecated, so `dst.descriptions = tuple(['Band 1 name', 'Band 2 name', 'Band 3 name'])` is now the way to go!